# finished with non-zero exit value 1 error return when spring boot application start to run

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-starter, versionupgrade

I updated my application to spring boot version 2.7.0 from 2.2.4. Java version is 8. Application built sucessfully but when I try to run the application with idea below error occurs.

```
Execution failed for task ':MyApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk1.8.0_342/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried to manually run the .jar file. But nothing happened. It exit from the java -jar command.